# 70's or 80's movie in which an older gentleman uses a magic paintbrush to paint living children into paintings they can't escape

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a 70's or 80's movie that I just can't find.

The movie has an older gentleman who would use a magic paintbrush (I seem to remember it was made out of a young girl's hair) to paint living children into paintings they can't escape. I know the scene in *The Witches*, but that's not it. A large amount of the plot was centered around this, but I can't remember anything else about it.

Answer (score 21):

This does sound to me very much like *[The Peanut Butter Solution](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089789/?ref_=tt_urv)*, released in 1985, but with a few important differences. In the film a boy named Michael is scared by a ghost and loses all of his hair. He is given a magical formula to regrow it (in which the active ingredient is peanut butter), but finds that his hair grows at an enormous rate.

He is captured by an ex-art teacher known as the "Signor", who uses Michael's hair to make paint brushes. These brushes are magical, in that they can create wonderfully realistic scenes of whatever the painter has in his mind. The Signor captures a group of children to put them to work in the paintbrush factory, making these magical brushes from Michael's hair, but they are imprisoned there by conventional means (nets, bars and traps) rather than being painted into pictures.

So it has the right ingredients: magic paintbrushes, made from a child's hair, an older gentleman as the villain, and children who are imprisoned. The paintings are so realistic that it is possible to step into them, but that does not let the children escape, as the scenes are of fictional locations.

Eventually one of the children persuades the Signor to paint the haunted house where Michael was scared by the ghost. The Signor enters the picture of the house, is scared by the same ghost, and the curse transfers to him - all his hair drops out. The children are then liberated by the police, assisted by Michael's father, who have tracked the Signor down using conventional methods

Comment: What an absolutely chaos trip of a movie.

Comment: @T.Sar I'm not sure my summary really does it justice  ;)

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you're describing an episode of the TV show *Are You Afraid of The Dark?* from 1995:  [The Tale of the Unfinished Painting](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Unfinished_Painting).

In it, a young girl meets a woman at an art gallery full of paintings.  Many paintings adorn the walls, some of which are unfinished.  As it turns out, the paintings are done by children who then become trapped inside.  At one point the woman becomes angry with a child because she isn't using the correct (cursed) paintbrush.  Even though it's a television show from the 90's and not a movie from the 70s or 80s, I'm fairly confident this is the story you're thinking of.

Answer (score 5):

Is it perhaps [The Pagemaster](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110763/), starring Macaulay Culkin and Christopher Lloyd?

It came out in the early 90s, features an older gentleman (Lloyd) who transforms the protagonist into an animated illustration, forcing him to go through a bunch of challenges before he can escape back to his life.

Cons:
Does not feature a magic paintbrush.